# How to achieve calendar design like Peek Calendar in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, calendar

Does anyone have suggestions on how to achieve this type of Calendar view (image below)?

Any help will be appreciated

[image]

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve "showing tableView on tap of date", I would suggest:

1. Create a TableView with custom cells. These customCell should contain 5 buttons. The custom cells will have, cell.tag == indexPath.row .
2. On tap of button just change its appearance,(Like background from blue -> white). Then post a notification with cellTag in its object.
3. The receiver of the notification will be our main tableViewController Screen. It will add a row at IndexPath.row == cellTag + 1.
4. You can add a new row, which contains another customCell with tableView.
5. Or you can also add tableView as a section FooterView. In this case, you will have to add 1 row in each section, and keep cell.tag == indexPath.section. So you will show/ hide sectionFooter View. And reload tableview.

For Animation:

Given Eg: uses page fold animation, there are various libraries for the same.You can try

1. https://github.com/jackyzh/awesome-ios-animation
2. https://github.com/mpospese/MPFoldTransition

I haven't tested them with newer iOS versions. But this will surely give you a head start.

Comment: Thanks for reply @user3300864,  For the folding animation i found one more example (link:-  https://github.com/rbobbins/animation-demo), My main concern is for Calendar View on how to achieve open a tableview while clicking on any specific date. Create our own calendar using uicollectionview?

Comment: @BrianTompsett-汤莱恩 I agree. i will include the important section.